# Changing row names in to numerical index in R's data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I do that? For example currently we have this:

```
> head(mtcars,n=2L)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

I want to change it to:

```
  carnames        mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

That is change row names into column with title `car names` and then the new row names
just use standard numerical number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
mtcars$carnames <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

head(mtcars)
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb          carnames
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4         Mazda RX4
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     Mazda RX4 Wag
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        Datsun 710
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    Hornet 4 Drive
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet Sportabout
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           Valian
```

Comment: But note that custom rownames are as character vectors: `is.character(rownames(mtcars))` is TRUE.  Here you're really better off setting the rownames to NULL, `rownames(mtcars) <- NULL`, which doesn't actually store all the rownames internally.